# How to open the page in firefox to render HTML5 content?

Tags: html

How to open the page in firefox browser to **render** `HTML5` content?

```
 MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
function RunFirefox() {
    MyObject.Run("firefox file:///C:/Users/E836714/Desktop/template%20palettes/preview.html");

}
```

Here, I use `url` to open the `Page`. What I need was instead of `url`, I pass `HTML` to render in firefox.

Comment: not need to pass the  full path  just give folder name and file name  like  template%20palettes/preview.html

Comment: i need to pass html instead of file url do you have any ideas

Comment: Save html and then pass the filename?

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveXObject object is used to create instances of OLE Automation objects in **Internet Explorer** on **Windows operating systems**.

So it only supports Internet Explorer on Windows. No other browser support is available till date for ActiveXObject.